# Node.js - isInteger returns false when it should return true

Tags: javascript, node.js

Straight to the point, I've got this code:

```
//SERVERSIDE
newSocket.on("connectOrb", function(connectingOrbId, targetOrbId)
{
    if(Number.isInteger(connectingOrbId) && (Number.isInteger(targetOrbId)))
    {
        //FURTHER VALIDATION...
    }
}

//CLIENTSIDE
socket.emit("connectOrb", parseInt(selectedOrbElement.attr("cid")), parseInt(clickedOrbElement.attr("cid")));
```

When I check if `connectingOrbId` and `targetOrbId` are integers on localhost, everything works fine, both conditions returns true and algorithm continues, but when I host this app on OpenShift and try to do the exact same thing, then I can't pass this validation, what could be the problem?

By the way, when I `console.log(connectingOrbId)` and `console.log(targetOrbId)` I get numbers that I should get (so it's not `undefined`).

EDIT:

So I've tweaked serverside code a bit, but i'm still getting same result:

```
newSocket.on("connectOrb", function(connectingOrbId, targetOrbId)
{
    connectingOrbId = parseInt(connectingOrbId);
    targetOrbId = parseInt(targetOrbId);

    if(Number.isInteger(connectingOrbId) && (Number.isInteger(targetOrbId)))
    {
        //FURTHER VALIDATION...
    }
}
```

EDIT2:

As Rafael asked I've checked for the type of these variables, so now the code looks like this:

```
newSocket.on("connectOrb", function(connectingOrbId, targetOrbId)
{
    connectingOrbId = parseInt(connectingOrbId);
    targetOrbId = parseInt(targetOrbId);

    console.log("Connecting: "+typeof connectingOrbId);
    console.log("Target: "+typeof targetOrbId);

    if(Number.isInteger(connectingOrbId) && (Number.isInteger(targetOrbId)))
    {
        //FURTHER VALIDATION...
    }
}
```

And console approves that both of these are Number type variables.

EDIT 3:

So as Mike helped me find out I had an old node.js version on OpenShift and a new one locally, updating an old version fixed the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you are receiving a number and not a string?

Comment: I would think the same, but the thing is that when I test this out locally everything works perfectly and when I host it to the OpenShift server I can't pass this validation.

Comment: Why don't you `parseInt` the args anyway? If you say you are receiving them in the callback, but the validation fails, the only reasonable explanation is that `isInteger` returns false. BTW, you should add the base to your `parseInt` like `parseInt(n, 10)`

Comment: Well, now I've parsed it again and still getting the same result

Comment: Do you was try see the value by connectingOrbId and targetOrbId? And their types (with typeof)

Comment: @RafaelDantas Console says that both of these variables are numbers.

Comment: Please provide some example data that is causing this. You might also check the version of Node you are using locally versus that used at OpenShift.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Checked the versions - locally: 4.4.4, on server: 0.10 so probably that's the case, I'll update my version and post the results.

Comment: So I've changed node.js version on server and everything works fine, Thank you, Mike.